# I read my text file, now how do I store the values into a 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

As mentioned, I already managed to read in the file, I'm looking for a method to added to a 2D array. This is what I read:

20  10  8

4.5  8.45  12.2

8.0  2.5  4.0

1.0  15.0  18.0

3.5  3.5  3.5

6.0 5.0 10.0

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Packages 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,FileNotFoundException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Dimensions.txt"));
        while (true) 
        {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if(line==null);
            {
                 break;
            }
        System.out.println(line);

        }
        reader.close();  
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution uses a 2D array to store the numbers from your file.  This would be an appropriate solution if the structure of your input is both known and well-defined.  By this I mean that every row has three numbers, and you also know how many rows there are.  If not, then you might want to use a Java collection class instead here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    // change this value to whatever row count you actually have
    int NUM_ROWS = 100;
    double[][] array = new double[NUM_ROWS][3];
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Dimensions.txt"));

    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (line == null) break;
        String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
        for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i) {
            array[counter][i] = Double.parseDouble(parts[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(line);
        ++counter;
    }
    reader.close();  
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=0; i < 3 && i < part.length; ++i)`

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, I don't think we should even be using an array if the structure of the input file could have columns of varying width.

Comment: Gee, I don't think we should be using an Array at all even if with non-varying number of columns, but input files do get messed up, and safety checks should be put in place.  You code will fail if the file has more than 100 rows or someone accidentally deletes a CRLF halfway through the file.

Comment: Checking for error in the input file has little to do with using an array versus a collection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a scanner to read the line, `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line)`.
2. Create a loop that reads next item, `scanner.next()` or `scanner.nextDouble()` while it has next.
3. Put each into array at its given spot by maintaining a count for `lineNumber` and `doubleCount`. If you do not know the dimension size you will have to do a loop that counts each line and another that counts how many doubles in the line.